# U05D2 Fundamental Counting Principle Practice

Tags: probability

Let’s say a bank implements some restrictions on their pin numbers.  1 They cannot all be the same number, 2 They cannot be all in numerical order forward or reverse {exp. 1111, 0123, or 0987 would not be ok}.  How many possible pin numbers do we have to pick from now?  (Note: A 0 can be below 1 or above 9 for numerical order)

How many numerical order and same digit combinations would there be: _

How many valid pin numbers would there be: _

Let’s say a bank implements some restrictions on their pin numbers.  1 They cannot all be the same number, 2 They cannot be all in numerical order forward or reverse {exp. 1111, 0123, or 0987 would not be ok}.  How many possible pin numbers do we have to pick from now?  (Note: A 0 can be below 1 or above 9 for numerical order)